# Unable to redirect to another page using angular js

Tags: angularjs, redirect

I am trying to redirect to another page on successful login, but instead of redirecting to another page, I am getting redirected to the default page which is:

```
.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    })
```

`.

**Angular code:**

```
if(res.status == 200){
            console.log($scope.user);
            alert('Login successfull');
            $location.path('http://localhost:3000/#!/products/add-mew-product');
        }
```

Why this is happening, please help.

Comment: did you mean to redirect to `add-mew-product` ? or `add-new-product`

Comment: it's `add-mew-product` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to pass the whole url, instead of it pass as below

```
 $location.path('/products/add-mew-product');
```

or you can directly use

```
 $window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/#/products/add-mew-product';
```

Comment: `$window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/#!/products/add-mew-product';`, is not working`$location.path('/products/add-mew-product');` this working., Thanks :)